# Why does this SSH host key fingerprint not match the pattern when using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: regex, ssh, fingerprint, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server using WinSCP and PowerShell and have hit the following snag

> Error: SSH host key fingerprint "ssh-rsa 2048 ABCDE+I9v1+pLxkhZkod6yAbEh0o7a8wlSsI+ABCDEF" does not match pattern
>       /((ssh-rsa|ssh-dss|ssh-ed25519|ecdsa-sha2-nistp(256|384|521))( |-))?(\d+ )?(([0-9a-f]{2}(:|-)){15}[0-9a-f]{2}|[0-9a-zA-Z+/]{43}=)(;((ssh-rsa|ssh-dss|ssh-ed25519|ecdsa-sha2-nistp(256|384|521))( |-))?(\d+ )?(([0-9a-f]{2}(:|-)){15}[0-a-f]{2}|[0-9a-zA-Z+/]{43}=))*/

The ABCDE and ABCDEF in the quoted string are just me obscuring the fingerprint.

I've checked the existing SO responses (
[SSH host key fingerprint ... does not match pattern ... when using WinSCP .NET assembly in C# to download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204629/ssh-host-key-fingerprint-does-not-match-pattern-when-using-winscp-net-a), [SSH host key fingerprint does not match pattern C# WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050307/ssh-host-key-fingerprint-does-not-match-pattern-c-sharp-winscp)) but they don't apply.

I have a vague knowledge of regular expressions, and it looks like it should match to me, so I hope I am missing something simple. I have the 'ssh-rsa', then a space ( |-), then a number of digits followed by space (\d+ ), then 43 characters that match [0-9a-zA-Z+/]{43} (it's the fact that I have a 43-character string that makes me thing I have a correct fingerprint and am just missing some syntactic trivia). The whole of the second half of the pattern is just a repeat of the first, and I'm assuming an optional one, so I don't know what's not being accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Base-64 encoded SHA-256 fingerprint [should be padded with `=`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding):

```
ssh-rsa 2048 ABCDE+I9v1+pLxkhZkod6yAbEh0o7a8wlSsI+ABCDEF=
```

---

Though note that since WinSCP 5.17, the padding is not required.

---

Also as mentioned in answers to both questions you have referred to, [WinSCP can generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) including the correct fingerprint for you.